# What is the point of Java's File constructor

Tags: java

I read it makes a representation of the PATH of a file.

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("location.txt");
File file2 = new File(file); //new File("location.txt");
```

is this the correct usage if the file does not readily exist? what is its purpose and uses

Comment: From [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) javadoc: *An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.*

Comment: From [`java.io.FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) javadoc: *Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why even use File when I can skip straight to FileWriter" You *don't* have to use File.  It may simply be more convenient in some situations, but not the situation you're describing.  It doesn't make any difference if the file exists, or doesn't exist.

In fact, if you dig down in the source code, `new FileWriter(String)` delegates to `new FileOutputStream(String)` which essentially does `this(new File(String))`, so the semantics will be exactly the same.  It's just that one or the other might be more convenient in certain situations.

Comment: thanks, my biggest problem was trying to understand when I would use file over filewrite, because they seem to do the same thing. The book headintojava simply says its safer but does not explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
File file = new File("location.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

If the file does not exist, it will be created, and you can then write to it (edit the contents), using:

```
writer.write("What you want to write"); 
writer.flush();
writer.close(); //<-this is VERY IMPORTANT
```

Comment: thanks, this is the point of my question, why even use File when I can skip straight to FileWriter. From what I have been reading, I am guessing that maybe the file path is long and you want to condense the name..? lol.

Comment: *If the file does not exist, it will be created* this is partially true. From javadoc: *Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform.* If working in Windows or Linux, it could be created if the user that executes the application have enough privileges, otherwise, it will throw an `IOException`.

Comment: I you want to just use FileWriter, you have to use `FileWriter write = new FileWriter(new File("location.txt"));`. There's no way around it.

Comment: @JacobHong because the `FileWriter` or any other class or library that wants to work with OS physical files needs a representation of the file being modified. This is achieved using the `File` class.